# How to call parent class's Symbol.iterator from within child's Symbol.iterator

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have the following two classes in TypeScript.

```
class BaseIter {
  constructor(public a: number, public b: number, public c: number, public d: number){}
  *[Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<number> {
    yield this.a
    yield this.b
    yield this.c
    yield this.d
  }
}

class MyIter extends BaseIter {
  get total() {
    return this.a + this.b + this.c + this.d
  }

  *[Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<number> {
    for(let x of this){
      yield x  
    }
    yield this.total
  }
}

const myIter = new MyIter(1, 2, 3, 4);

for (let n of myIter){
  console.log(n);
}
```

The `BaseIter` class takes in four arguments, and yields those four argument back when iterated. I have child class that extends `BaseIter` which is supposed to use the parents iteration function but also yield an extra value (the total). The current code doesn't work - it causes an infinite recursion (iterating over `this` calls the same function, instead of the base function). I've tried various methods of `super` without luck.

I expect it to produce

```
1
2
3
4
10
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If it was a normal method, I could just use `super.method()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generator functions have a return type of `IterableIterator<T>`, not `Iterator<T>`. This was preventing TypeScript from being able to consume the method from the super class as an iterable. In general, you should let TypeScript infer the return value of your functions unless it warns you that it is not able to.

```
class BaseIter {
  constructor(public a: number, public b: number, public c: number, public d: number) {}

  * [Symbol.iterator] () {
    yield this.a;
    yield this.b;
    yield this.c;
    yield this.d;
  }
}

class MyIter extends BaseIter {
  get total () {
    return this.a + this.b + this.c + this.d;
  }

  * [Symbol.iterator] () {
    yield * super[Symbol.iterator]();
    yield this.total;
  }
}

const myIter = new MyIter(1, 2, 3, 4);

for (const n of myIter) {
  console.log(n);
}
```

Comment: hrm, I thought I got the return type from some other tutorial on generators, guess it was wrong? Anyways, this makes loads of sense, thanks!

Comment: @blitzmann the return type of generator functions do implement the iterator interface, but it's important for this particular example that they implement the iterable interface as well, otherwise they're not a valid target of the `yield*` operator (or `for...of` loop).